# How to search id / item from an array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a `$_SESSION` id's of an item

for example i have this items

```
$_SESSION['items'] = array(1,4,5,7,8);
```

and I have a data from database

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");

while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   // Here in the loop; I want to Search 
   // $row['id'] if exist in $_SESSION['items']
   // if exist I want to display 'YES' else 'NO'
}
```

How to do the right code for this ?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `in_array` https://www.php.net/in_array

```
if(in_array($row['id'], $_SESSION['items']))
```